# How to stay on same position after submitting an html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a simple html form:

```
<form action="addToCart" method="post"><br><br> 

    <input name="productId"
value="${product.id}" type="hidden"> <input class="submit" onclick="addedCart()" value="<fmt:message key='AddToCart'/>"
type="submit"> 


</form>
```

Every time I click on "submit", it brings me straight back to top which creates a poor user experience because the user would have to scroll back down where he was browsing the products... Can I do this without using a script?

Comment: You should post this form using `ajax`

Comment: submit with ajax.....!

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is your best bet if you want to achieve what you want

```
 $('.submit').on('click',function(event){
     event.preventDefault(); //this is important else page will get submitted
     $.ajax({
      url:'where you want to process data',
      dataType:'html',
      data: your form data as json or whatever type
      success: function(result){
      //here you can update any thing on the frontside
      }
     });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

*-Every time I click on "submit", it brings me straight back to top.*

Yes that is what default functionality when submitting forms, it always repaints the dom so it causes a jump and page's top position is rendered.

*-which creates a poor user experience because the user would have to scroll back down where he was browsing the products*

To make a good user experience you can use ajax for this functionality, as you tagged jQuery in your question then you can try with jquery ajax:

```html
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stops the form submission

    $.ajax({
      url:$(this).attr('action'), // action attribute of form to send the values
      type:$(this).attr('method'), // method used in the form
      data:$(this).serialize(), // data to be sent to php
      dataType:"text",
      success:function(data){
          alert(data); // you can alert the success message.
      },
      error:function(err){
          console.log(err);
      }
    });

});
```

---

I have used a `dataType:"text",` just assuming if you are going to `echo "Added in the cart.";` kind of message from the php.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `onclick` attribute on your button, you have to change `type` attribute from `submit` to `button`. That way you can get your `addedCart()` method to fire. Then handle form submission inside that method (if your submit handler isn't already there).

```
<input class="submit" onclick="addedCart()" value="<fmt:message key='AddToCart'/>" type="button">
```

Script:

```
function addedCart(){
    // ... your method on click
    // $.ajax({...});
};
```

If you're not using jQuery, you can handle form submission with `XMLHttpRequest` :
 
[How to make an AJAX call without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery?answertab=votes)